# Can't link Refresh Control to IBAction in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get a Refresh Control to link to an IBAction function in my View Controller.  When I ctrl-drag it only gives me the option to create an Outlet.
I added the Refresh Control simply by setting Refreshing to Enabled in the Attributes Inspector.

Everything else is set up properly as far as I'm aware, the View Controller is set in the Identity inspector and I'm attempting to link to the correct Class.

Any Advice

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not your solution of your problem.But you can create Refresh Control programmatically.Like...

```
    var refreshCntrl : UIRefreshControl!
    refreshCntrl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshCntrl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    refreshCntrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Loading...")
    refreshCntrl.addTarget(self, action:("refreshControlValueChanged"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    atableView.addSubview(refreshCntrl)
```

//Method of RefreshControl

```
func refreshControlValueChanged(){
    atableView.reloadData()
    refreshCntrl.endRefreshing()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too, it gives you an Outlet option because you didn't select the button as you thought but the bar. Hence, for letting it set an Action you need to higlight the Bar Button in your controller's top-down menu on the left column.

Hope it helps!